# How can I use apply_filters or add_filter only on certain post types?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to edit the markup of images, but only for one custom post type. How can I apply the filter to only that post type?

I've tried querying for the post type inside the function and outside of it.

```php
function custom_email_images($html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url) {
  $post_type = get_post_type();
  if ( 'email-layout' === $post_type ) {
    $src = wp_get_attachment_url($id);
    $html = '<img src="' . $src . '?w=800" width="415" style="width:415px;max-width:100%">';
  }
  return $html;
}

apply_filters(
  'image_send_to_editor',
  'custom_email_images',
  10,
  6
);
```

Comment: How are things? Did you try my suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

get_post_type() defaults to get_post_type($post).
The function doesn't know about the global $post variable by itself though.

Try adding this into the function at the top and see if it works:

```
global $post;
```

Otherwise try to print_r or echo out get_post_type and see what it is (currently it's probably "false").